# JavaFX AnimationTimer VS Swing Game Loop

Tags: game-loop, javafx

After looking at some code sources out there I noticed Java Swing Games usually create a class implementing Runnable, create a `new Thread` and set up the game loop in the `run()` call.

But JavaFX games seem to simply extend from `Application` and run the game loop in a  `new AnimationTimer() { ... public void handle() ... }`

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application` is part of JavaFX and therefore can't be used without it and since a JavaFX app relies on the lifecycle of this class and JavaFX requires a class that extends Application, it would be impossible to not use it when creating programs with the library.

Comment: Also, an Animation Timer automatically registers with the JavaFX pulse system (which has a dafault rate of 60fps, can be changed though) so it does the loopinp, timing and sleeping for you.